# WebViewClassic NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My application gets force closed but from looking at the stacktrace none of my code is actually being referenced, and I don't use a WebViewClassic object. Any ideas?

```
?:??: W/?(?): java.lang.NullPointerException
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setBaseLayer(WebViewClassic.java:4447)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setNewPicture(WebViewClassic.java:7825)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebViewClassic.java:7211)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
?:??: W/?(?):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```